# Django selecting objects in_bulk()

Tags: django

I am trying to use in_bulk method, although something goes wrong

First I pick values into list that I need to select in bulk:

```
states = StateObjectRelation.objects.filter(state=int(3), content_type=int(ctype.id))
```

Then convert them to list:

```
list = values_list('content_id', flat=True)
```

Now selecting the items in_bulk:

```
projects = Project.objects.in_bulk(list)
```

Give me the following error:

Exception Value:
in_bulk() must be provided with a list of IDs.

If i print out the values that are in list I get the following:

```
>>> print list
[1L]
>>> print list.values()
[{'state_id': 3L, 'content_id': 1L, 'id': 1L, 'content_type_id': 29L}]
```

Comment: `list` is a name of built-in list type, it's a very bad idea to name variable like that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, it's a mistake to call your list `list`, since that's a reserved word (function) in Python. But as for your question, all you need to do is make a list of your query first, like this:

`list2 = list(l)`

or like this (slower):

`list2 = [l for l in list]`

Then you really have a real `list` object, and not just something that appears like one when you print it. Now you should be able to call

`projects = Project.objects.in_bulk(list2)`

Comment: I'll see whether I can think of something more efficient, but it's not too horrible, and in your case it should be fine. Also, as @vartec mentioned, please change your variable name to something else.

Comment: Why not just wrap it in `list()` ? as in `list(values_list('content_id', flat=True))`. Obviously you shouldn't call the queryset "list"...

Answer (score 4):

I would simply do it like that, using `list()`:

```
ids = list(your_queryset.values_list('content_id', flat=True))
projects = Project.objects.in_bulk(ids)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered, but these answers seem to be inefficient. 
The output of a flat `values_list()` is perfectly acceptable as the list of values for `in_bulk()`

```
content_id_pks = StateObjectRelation.objects.filter(state=int(3), content_type=int(ctype.id)).values_list('content_id', flat=True)
projects = Project.objects.in_bulk(content_id_pks)
```

Note that projects isn't a queryset, it's a dictionary, which presents it's own set of handling problems in re: efficiency.